# How fast can Sobolev functions grow?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

It is a simple fact that $L^p$-functions cannot grow arbitrarily fast. More precisely, one has for every $\ell>0$
$$ |\{f\geq\ell\}|\leq \frac{\|f\|_{L^p}^p}{\ell^p} $$
for every $f\in L^p$.

My question is: Can this result be improved if e.g. $f\in W^{1,p}$? From intuition I'd expect something like  $ |\{f\geq\ell\}|\leq \frac{\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}^p}{\ell^{p+1}} $...

Comment: Yes, by Sobolev embedding theorem.

Comment: It will also depend on the dimension of the space, i.e. if you're looking at $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then it will also depend on $n$.

Comment: Of course! Good shout. 

Although, that imposes conditions on the domain and the dimension, I think that's good enough for me.